# Using parallelism to speed up the code

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I've made a tool that sends HTTP requests (GET) (reads the info of what to send from a .txt), captures the json and parses it + writes it to a .txt. The tool is a console app targetting .NET Framework 4.5.

Could I possibly speed this up with the help of "multi-threading"?

```cs
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(@"file.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.website.com/");
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("index?userGetLevel=" + line).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dynamic json = JObject.Parse(result);
                string level = json.data.level;

                if (level == "null")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: User does not exist.", line);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: User level is {1}.", line, level);

                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(levels.txt))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line, level);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        file.Close();
```

---

**Answers to questions:**

**"Speed up what?":** I'd like to speed up the whole process (the amount of requests it sends each time, not how fast it sends them.

**"How many requests?":** The tool reads a string from a text file and puts that information in to a part of the URL, and then captures the response, then places that in a result.txt. I'd like to increase the speed it does this at/how many it does at a time.

**"Can the requests happen concurrently or are dependant on prior request responses?":** Yes, and no, they are not dependent.

**" Does your web server impose a limit on the number of concurrent requests?":** No.

**"How long does a typical request take?":** The request + the time the response shows up on console per each requests is a little bit more than 1/3 of a second.

Comment: You can use [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of thread, place your code here to improve.

Comment: Normally this would be IO work, wich would not benefit from Multithreading. However with WebAPI's a few extra thigns factor in: The CPU overhead of hte Protocoll. The Fact that the server is propably massively Paralell. so multiple request can run in paralell. So yes, in case of Web Requests Multithreading or -Tasking **can** speed it up to some degree. However the final limit will be either the Disk or the Network connection to the server, not usually the CPU. And that all asumes the other side is not protected from being spammed with Requests. It also asumes there is no "bulk request" call.

Comment: @MickyD Updated the thread!

Comment: Added code as well.

Comment: Thank-you.  Nomintated for re-opening.  Until then, though you could probably do this sort of think with many concurrent `Task`s; because yours is essentially a pipeline problem (read from file; send to web; wait for response; write response to disk); you may want to look at _TPL DataFlow_ - a graph/flow metaphor.  It's a bit more complex but the beauty is that you have complete control of concurrency for each stage of the process; and each stage can be re-used to handle multiple requests at a time (batching) making it more efficient

Comment: @Pedram Added my code.

Comment: @MickyD I read some about it, but think it might be a bit too complicated for me. I just recently started with C#.

Comment: Ah ok.  Yes read-up on `async/await` and use `Task`s if  you are using .NET 4 and beyond.  It's the easiest way to do "threading". (quick tip: a `Task` is not a thread).  Give that a Google

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: @CandyGum: And also I recommend you to change the title of question to something like: "Using parallelism to speed up the code" or ...

Comment: @CandyGum Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Pedram Replied to your answer :)

Comment: @CandyGum ok I have updated the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to asymmetric programming, one of them could be something like this:

```
var messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
//or
//var lockObj = new object();

public int main()
{
    var fileText = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");

    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var line in fileText)
    {
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(HandlerMethod, line));
        //you can control the amount of produced task if you want:
        //if(taskList.Count > 20)
        //{
        //    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        //    taskList.Clear();
        //}
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray()); //this line may not work as I expected.

    //for the first way
    var results = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var msg in messages)
    {
        results.AppendLine("{0} : {1}", line, level);
    }
    File.WriteAllText("path", results.ToString());
}
```

For writing the results, either you can use a public concurrent collection or use a [lock pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern):

```
public void HandlerMethod(object obj)
{
    var line = (string)obj;
    var result = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.website.com/");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("index?userGetLevel=" + line).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        dynamic json = JObject.Parse(result);
        result = json.data.level;
    }

    //for the first way
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
    {
        messages.Enqueue("{0}: User does not exist.", line);
    }
    else
    {
        messages.Enqueue("{0}: User level is {1}.", line, result);
    }

    //for the second way
    //lock(lockObj)
    //{
    //    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(levels.txt))
    //    {
    //        sw.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line, level);
    //    }
    //}
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this kind of worked. The only issue is that it prints out stuff in wrong order sometimes, and even crashes because it can't access the "valid.txt" file. (Guessing this is because the tasks run in to eachother? Any way I can fix this?

Comment: @CandyGum No, it is not related to the tasks, because the file is only accessed in the main thread. I will update the code soon, try it.

Comment: Thank you, but I still recieve the error. To solve it (for testing purposes), I removed all the StreamWriters, and the code seems to work without any errors, but then it obviously dosn't save the results. Also, with tasking, the console output is really off, the color changes and Console.Write()'s come in weird orders :/

Comment: yes, while you are saving a file with multiple tasks you should use a lock pattern. I will update the code soon.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much, sir, I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: ´using (var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)))´ This did it for me, with your second method. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Don't mention it! I’m happy to help.